# Searching for an image element whose src contains a keyword, in an iFrame's HTML using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am digging deep into a page's DOM to manipulate a certain image attribute. I have a web page which contains an iFrame. The iFrame contains an image. The image has no id attribute so I am going to locate it using it's src. The src contains the unique keyword 'planet'. How do I locate this image using jQuery?

**ADDITION:**

I can't reference anything in the iFrame's DOM. Is there a special way to reference an element inside an iFrame?

Example: alert( $(myIframe).find('html').length ) reports 0, expecting 1.

Comment: you will have to get the iframe the write your query against the content of that iframe.  The trick here will be if the iframe is in a different domain you will not be able to dive into it to extract data in most browsers.

Comment: The iFrame is created by a third party tool. I don't have control over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can manipulate iframe contents if the iframe's domain is not one you have control over.

**EDIT:** Since you said that it IS from the same domain now, `$('#id').contents().find('a')` should work.

Comment: +1 you can't it breaks the security model of browsers. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533028%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: IFrame source is from the same site. It's actually ASP.NET's report viewer.

Comment: Edited my answer based on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
   var img = $('iframe img[src|=planet]');
});
```